# Instagram Scraper - Empty Dataframe

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, instagram

Currently trying to run this code for hashtag scraping:

https://github.com/kitsamho/Instagram_Scraper_Graph/blob/master/InstagramScraper.ipynb

But it keeps returning an empty dataframe.

```
    class InstagramScraper():

"""
Class that allows you to scrape the content of Instagram posts, either
a profile or a hashtag.

Initialised with the location of your Chromedriver location

"""

def __init__(self,driver_loc='C:/Users/gctia/Documents/Python Scripts/basf/chromedriver.exe'):

    self.driver_loc = driver_loc

def multithreadCompile(self,thread_count,iteration_list,func):

    """
    This function compiles the batched needed for mult-threadding

    Args:

        thread_count is the number of threads used for multi-threadding

        iteration_list is the source list of urls to iterate over

        func is the function to be used in the multi-thredding process

    Returns:

        The batches that have been allocated to be run using the specified
        function

    """

    jobs = [] #empty list for jobs

    #distribute iteration list to batches and append to jobs list
    batches = [i.tolist() for i in np.array_split(iteration_list,thread_count)]

    for i in range(len(batches)):

        jobs.append(threading.Thread(target=func,args=[batches[i]]))

    return jobs

def multithreadExecute(self,jobs):

    """

    This function executes the multi-threadding process

    Args:

        The batches that have been appended to a jobs list

    Returns:

        Nothing, merely executes the multi-threadding

    """

    # Start the threads
    for j in jobs:
        print('execute working')
        j.start()

    # Ensure all of the threads have finished
    for j in jobs:

        j.join()

    return

def getJson(self,url):

    """
    This function exracts a JSON style dictionary from the html for any
    given unique Instagram post

    Args:

        An Instagram post URL

    Returns:

        JSON dictionary ouput

    """

    page = urlopen(url).read() #read url

    data=BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser') #get a BeautifulSoup object

    body = data.find('body') #find body element

    script = body.find('script') #find script element

    #some string formatting
    raw = script.text.strip().replace('window._sharedData =', '').replace(';', '')

    #load string
    json_data=json.loads(raw)

    return json_data #return JSON dictonary

def userDetails(self):

    """
    Functions that capture log in details and logs user into Instagram

    Args:

        None needed

    Returns:

        Nothing

    """
    #capture username
    username = input('Enter username...')

    #capture password
    password = getpass.getpass('Enter password...')

    self._password = password #retain password as attribute

    self._username = username #retain user name as attribute

    return

def openWebdriver(self):

    """
    Launches Chrome webdriver

    Args:

        None needed

    Returns:

        driver

    """

    #intiate driver
    print("Launching driver...")

    #retain current driver as attribute
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(self.driver_loc)

    return driver

def closeWebdriver(self,driver):

    """
    Closes Chrome webdriver

    Args:

        webDriver

    Returns:

        Nothing

    """

    driver.close()

    return

def instagramLogin(self,driver):

    """
    Logs in to Instagram

    Args:

        Current webdriver

    Returns:

        Current webdriver - logged into Instagram

    """

    #base url
    driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher')

    sleep(2) #wait

    #log in
    #username_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div/label/input')
    username_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']")))

    #username_field.click() #click on username button

    #send username
    username_field.send_keys(self._username)

    #locate element to click
    #try:
    #    password_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div/label/input')

    #except:
    #    password_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[4]/div/label/input')
    password_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password']")))

    #password_field.click()

    password_field.send_keys(self._password)

    sleep(2)

    #find log in button
    #login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[4]')
    login_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()


    #login_button.click()

    sleep(3)

    #locate floating window to click and close
    #floating_window = driver.find_element_by_class_name('piCib')

    #button = floating_window.find_element_by_class_name('mt3GC')

    #not_now = button.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]')

    #not_now.click()
    
    alert = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Not Now")]'))).click()
    alert2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Not Now")]'))).click()

    return driver

def setTarget(self):

    """
    Function that sets either a profile or a hashtag as a target

    Args:

        None

    Returns:

        base url to scrape - either a hashtag page or a profile page

    """

    #tou can choose either hashtag search or a profile to search
    route = input('What do you want to scrape, profile posts or hashtags? (p/h)')

    #if hashtags
    if route == 'h':

        #set hashtag
        hashtag = input('Which hashtag do you want to scrape posts for: ')

        self.target_label = '#'+hashtag #retain hashtag as attribute

        tag_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/' #set base url

        self._target = tag_url+hashtag #set url to scrape from

        return self._target #return url to scrape from

    else:

        profile = input('What profile do you want to scrape posts for: ')

        self.target_label = '@'+profile #retain profile as attribute

        profile_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/' #set base url

        self._target = profile_url+profile #set url to scrape from

        return self._target #return url to scrape from

def scrapeLinks(self,url):

    """
    Function that scrapes the links needed

    Args:

        target_url

    Returns:

        Nothing - but retains a list of urls to scrape

    """

    #pass url as argument to Selenium webDriver, loads url
    self.activedriver.get(url)

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    #start maximised
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

    #gets scroll height
    last_height = self.activedriver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    #initiate empty list for unique Instagram links
    links = []

    #some lines for user interactivity / selection of link target(n)
    print("\n")
    target = input("How many links do you want to scrape (minimum)?: ")
    print("\n")
    print("Staring Selenium scrape, please keep browser open.")
    print("\n")

    #this loops round until n links achieved or page has ended

    while True:

        source = self.activedriver.page_source

        data= BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

        body = data.find('body')

        #script = body.find('span')

        for link in body.findAll('a'):

            if re.match("/p", link.get('href')):

                links.append('https://www.instagram.com'+link.get('href'))

            else:
                continue

        # Scroll down to bottom
        self.activedriver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        # Wait to load page
        time.sleep(2)

        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = self.activedriver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

        #if no more content, scrape loop is terminated
        if new_height == last_height:
            break

        last_height = new_height

        #update on successful links scraped
        print("Scraped ", len(links)," links, ", len(set(links)),' are unique')

        #if n target met then while loop breaks
        if len(set(links))>int(target):
            break

    #links are saved as an attribute for the class instance
    self._links = list(unique_everseen(links))

    #clear the screen and provide user feedback on performance
    clear_output()

    print("Finished scraping links. Maxed out at ", len(links)," links, of which ", len(self._links),' are unique.')

    print("\n")

    print("Unique links obtained. Closing driver")

    print("\n")
    # close driver
    self.closeWebdriver(self.activedriver)

    return


def postDate(self,data):

    """
    Function that gets the date of post
    Args:
        JSON dictionary for post
    Returns:
        datetime of post
    """

    return datetime.utcfromtimestamp(data['entry_data']['PostPage'][0]['graphql']['shortcode_media']['taken_at_timestamp']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

def postUser(self,data):

    """
    Function that gets the username of the person who posted
    Args:
        JSON dictionary for post
    Returns:
        username
    """
    return data['entry_data']['PostPage'][0]['graphql']['shortcode_media']['owner']['username']

def postVerifiedUser(self,data):

    """
    Function gets the verified status of the user
    Args:
        JSON dictionary for post
    Returns:
        verified status
    """
    return data['entry_data']['PostPage'][0]['graphql']['shortcode_media']['owner']['is_verified']


def postLikes(self,data):

    """
    Function that gets the number of likes the post received
    Args:
        JSON dictionary for post
    Returns:
        number of likes
    """

    return data['entry_data']['PostPage'][0]['graphql']['shortcode_media']['edge_media_preview_like']['count']

def postVerifiedTags(self,data):

    """
    Function that gets the verified tags that a post contains
    Args:
        JSON dictionary for post
    Returns:
        the verified tags in the post
    """

    tag_end_point = data['entry_data']['PostPage'][0]['graphql']['shortcode_media']['edge_media_to_tagged_user']['edges']

    entities = []

    verif = []

    for i in range(len(tag_end_point)):

        entities.append(tag_end_point[i]['node']['user']['full_name'])

        verif.append(tag_end_point[i]['node']['user']['is_verified'])

    df = pd.DataFrame({'Brand':entities,'Verified':verif})

    df = df[df.Verified == True]

    if len(list(df.Brand)) < 1:

        return np.nan

    else:

        return list(df.Brand)

def postUnverifiedTags(self,data):

    """
    Function that gets the unverified tags a post contains
    Args:
        JSON dictionary for post
    Returns:
        the unverified tags in the post
    """

    tag_end_point = data['entry_data']['PostPage'][0]['graphql']['shortcode_media']['edge_media_to_tagged_user']['edges']

    tags = [] #emoty list for entities

    verif = [] #empty list for verified status

    #loop through
    for i in range(len(tag_end_point)):

        #append entities
        tags.append(tag_end_point[i]['node']['user']['full_name'])

        #append verified status
        verif.append(tag_end_point[i]['node']['user']['is_verified'])

    #DataFrame of verified / unverified tags
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Tag':tags,'Verified':verif})

    #subset on unverified tags
    df = df[df.Verified == False]

    #if there are unverified tags then return NaN else return unverified tags
    if len(list(df.Tag)) < 1:

        return np.nan

    else:

        return ''.join(list(df.Tag))

def postComment(self,data):

    return data['entry_data']['PostPage'][0]['graphql']['shortcode_media']['edge_media_to_caption']['edges'][0]['node']['text']

#get location of post
def postLocation(self,data):

    """
    Function that gets the post location if available
    Args:
        JSON dictionary for post
    Returns:
        the posts location
    """

    try:

        if len(list(data['entry_data']['PostPage'][0]['graphql']['shortcode_media']['location']['name'])) > 0:

            return data['entry_data']['PostPage'][0]['graphql']['shortcode_media']['location']['name']
    except:

        return np.nan

#get accessibility  / image data
def postAccessibility(self,data):
    
    """
    Function that gets the post accessibility data if available
    Args:
        JSON dictionary for post
    Returns:
        the accessibility data
    """

    try:
        try:
            image = data['entry_data']['PostPage'][0]['graphql']['shortcode_media']['accessibility_caption'].replace('Image may contain: ','').replace(' and ',', ').replace('one or more ','')

            return image

        except:
            image = data['entry_data']['PostPage'][0]['graphql']['shortcode_media']['edge_sidecar_to_children']['edges'][0]['node']['accessibility_caption'].replace('Image may contain: ','').replace(' and ',', ').replace('one or more ','')

            return image
    except:
        return np.nan

#return original post link
def postLink(self,data):

    return data


"""
The three main methods that combine all above
"""
#get user details, log in and initiate driver
def logIn(self):

    self.userDetails()

    driver = self.openWebdriver()

    self.activedriver = self.instagramLogin(driver)

    clear_output()

    print('Successfully logged in..ready to scrape')

#get all the unique links
def getLinks(self):

    return self.scrapeLinks(self.setTarget())

#extract data and return dataframe
def getData(self):

    #create empty lists for posts and comments
    post_date_l = []

    post_user_l = []

    post_verif_l = []

    post_likes_l = []

    post_tags_v_l =[]

    post_tags_u_l = []

    post_l = []

    post_location_l = []

    post_insta_classifier_l = []

    post_link_l = []

    self._listStack = [post_date_l,post_user_l,post_verif_l,post_likes_l,post_tags_v_l,
                  post_tags_u_l,post_l,post_location_l,post_insta_classifier_l,post_link_l]

    self._functionStack = [ self.postDate,
                                self.postUser,
                                self.postVerifiedUser,
                                self.postLikes,
                                self.postVerifiedTags,
                                self.postUnverifiedTags,
                                self.postComment,
                                self.postLocation,
                                self.postAccessibility,
                                self.postLink]

    def extractData(links=self._links):

        #loops through and calls each data collection function on each link
        for i in tqdm_notebook(range(len(links))):

            try:

                data = self.getJson(links[i])

                for function in self._functionStack:

                    if function != self._functionStack[-1]:

                        try:

                            self._listStack[self._functionStack.index(function)].append(function(data))

                        except:

                             self._listStack[self._functionStack.index(function)].append(np.nan)
                    else:
                        self._listStack[-1].append(self._functionStack[-1](links[i]))

            except:
                pass
        return

    # execute html parsing fuction using multi threading
    print("Attemping multi-threading...")

    print("\n")

    threads = int(input("How many threads?: "))

    print("\n")

    print("Executing...")

    self.multithreadExecute(self.multithreadCompile(threads,self._links,extractData))

    #set up intial data structure
    df = pd.DataFrame({'searched_for':[self.target_label]*len(post_l),
                       'post_link' :post_link_l,
                       'post_date':post_date_l,
                       'post':post_l,
                       'user':post_user_l,
                       'user_verified_status': post_verif_l,
                       'post_likes':post_likes_l,
                       'post_verified_tags':post_tags_v_l,
                       'post_unverified_tags':post_tags_u_l,
                       'post_location':post_location_l,
                       'post_image':post_insta_classifier_l,

                           })

    df.sort_values(by='post_date',ascending=False,inplace=True)

    df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True) #reset index

    self._df = df #retain final DataFrame as attribute
    
    return df
```

I'm using pretty much the same code, with some minor alterations on the instagramLogin function to be able to log in (not sure if that affected the scraping).

Comment: There is no `DataFrame` anywhere in that code

Comment: sorry, I meant to show just what I changed from the original code linked above, but edited to show the part I think is not working

Comment: Where are you appending the scraped data to the dataframe? It only seems you've initialized it.

Comment: I ran that code above (just the DataFrame section) through a text compare tool and it's an exact match to what is in the GitHub repo, for that code section.  So the code above shouldn't be the issue.  Have you actually run the GitHub code as-is? Does it work?  Obviously changing your User/PW but not touching anything else.  In your original code you touched a lot of things in that `instagramLogin` function. Try reverting back to the original, then changing one piece at a time and verifying it still works

Comment: @NikhilKumar my understanding is that the data is being appended once the getData function calls each item, I'm really not sure though.

Comment: @JD2775 I tried running the original code with no changes but I was having problems with the log in and its the only part I've modified